# Polymer.dart How to query for nodes inside the shadow root of a child custom element

Tags: dart, dart-webui, polymer

I have a parent component that serves as a container for other components. I want the container to be able to query for elements inside it's component.  For example, my outer component is:

```html
<polymer-element name="task-dart">
  <template>
      <div class="task-list">
        <template repeat="{{tasks}}">
          <task-row task="{{}}"></task-row>
        </template>
      </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="taskdart.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

And my inner component is:

```html
<polymer-element name="task-row" attributes="task">
  <template>
      <div class="task">
         <!-- html components of the task -->
      </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="task_row.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

But the neither of the following in taskdart.dart produce any results:

```dart
void created() {
    super.created();

    print(queryAll(".task").toString()); // []
    Timer.run( () {
        print("queryAll: " + queryAll(".task").toString()); // []
    });
}
```

Is this because the css is scoped in the internal component, or is because there's nothing to query at this point during initialization? Either way, how would I fix it?

Comment: You are crossing the shadow root boundary. Thus, you're breaking encapsulation. Not saying it's impossible, but you might think of how to do this without needing to understand the internal structure of a custom element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `shadowRoot`. It still won't do exactly what you're after (getting a list of the `.task'  elements, however.

Automatically, the contents of a polymer-element's top-level `<template>` is put into the shadow root.  That means that the `task-dart` can't query for div's in the child `<task-row>`s (they're contained within the `<task-row>`'s shadow root), it can only query it's own shadow root to get the list of task rows.

```dart
Timer.run( () {
  print("queryAll: " + this.shadowRoot.queryAll("task-row").toString()); // [task-row, task-row, task-row, task-row]
});
```

The [Polymer project has some links to Shadow DOM resources](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html) if you need some background reading.

Comment: From there I can get the internal div I want with taskRows[index].shadowRoot.query('.task')